# Check if docker container is stopped or failed

Tags: docker

I am attempting to check if (and handle all edge cases for) a container has been stopped or exited in an unclean state. I am using the `'State'` block returned by `docker inspect <container>` to attempt to resolve this.

```
    "State": {
        "Status": "exited",
        "Running": false,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 0,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2018-03-01T18:56:19.541980678Z",
        "FinishedAt": "2018-03-01T18:56:24.618264625Z"
    },
```

I know the `'ExitCode'` of a stopped container will be `137`, but there's a lot of other information there. Will filtering on `State.ExitCode == 137` be enough to filter for stopped instances?

EDIT: I should mention the reason why I am attempting to do this instead of using `pause` and `unpause` to manage my containers is that I want and active/standby arrangement of containers with port bindings. A container in `paused` state still maintains its port bindings which I need released when it is in `standby` state.

Comment: `docker ps -a` can give you all the containers list with their statues (exited, healthy, unhealthy...etc)

Comment: @zakariaamine are you adding any extra flags to that? All I get is CONTAINER_ID, IMAGE, COMMAND, CREATED, STATUS, PORTS and NAMES on my machine. I'm seeing a human-readable pruned version of what is presented in the `docker inspect` block, just in a less code-friendly way (e.g. `Exited (137) 2 days ago` after running `docker stop <container>`)

Comment: @zakariaamine in the `docker ps` documentation it specifies you can request status from `docker ps -a` as follows `status One of created, restarting, running, removing, paused, exited, or dead`. As you can see this does not have a concept of `stopped`, which is just lumped into `exited`. I am attempting to resolve the difference with all edge cases between an exit failure and a stop.

Comment: I see what you mean. With `docker ps`, you will not see the stopped ones, with `docker ps -a`, you will see all of them, so you can compare between the output of the two.

Comment: @zakariaamine I understand that, but it is less helpful than `docker inspect` in resolving stopped instances, so I don't know why I'd use it

Answer (score 4):

To get stopped container:

```bash
docker ps -f status=exited -f name=$container_name
```

See `docker ps` [filtering documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#filtering).